# different controller instance after calling another method in new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a controller with two methods: `a` and `b`. Method `a` initializes variable `var`.
I open a browser tab and call method `a`. After opening another tab, I call method `b` which reads `var` and I get a `nil`.

I inspected the console and was quite surprised that the `id` of the controller object is a different one when calling method `b`.

Shouldn't it be the same controller instance with access to variable `var` inside method `b` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails creates a new controller instance for each request. From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions):

> When your application receives a request, the routing will determine which controller and action to run, then Rails creates an instance of that controller and runs the method with the same name as the action.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi stefan, thanks for replying. in the first method i need to assign the var to use it afterwards in another method. more precisely, in the first method a, i create an instance of a webservice provider (@api_session), this will return a url which the user will visit and leaves the page. now he can open another url to see services from the api (method b), to show these services i need to have access to the formerly create var @api_session. best phil

Comment: You can use the [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) to store user specific data.

Comment: hi again, point being is that i dont want to store all the data in the session. i have method (browse) a which instantiates an api session object, now i create a html file with links in it, these links refer to a method in the same controller, which makes use of the api session object, so i need to have the same one. method browse is call via remote = true, even though the controller is a new instance. so how can i keep this api session object?

Comment: Please start a new question and include your controller code.

Comment: hi stefan,as requested I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512242/how-can-i-use-an-object-in-different-methods-within-the-same-controller