# How can I use an object in different methods within the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a controller with different methods.
In the first method, `authorize` I instantiate an object which I would like to reuse in another method. The problem is that both methods have different views, and the controller instance does not remain the same.

Hers is my code

```
def authorize
 @session ||= get_session
 puts @session
 @authorize_url = @session.get_authorize_url
end

def list
  puts self
  @session ||= get_session
  @client = DropboxClient.new(@session, ACCESS_TYPE)
  metadata = get_meta_data("/")
  @files = []
  metadata.each do |data|
   @files.push data
  end
  @files
end
```

So how can I reuse the @session variable?

Best
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, really. Each public method in your controller that renders a view is meant to be an endpoint for a request. The request's lifecycle ends there.

To persist data between requests, you should use sessions. This might be a bit more confusing, since you are indeed trying to persist an instance variable called `@session` between requests, but that's what they're for.

Rails exposes session data through a `session` hash available in your controllers. More information about how Rails handles sessions is available in the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
    def authorize
        @session ||= get_session
        session[:dropbox_session] = @session
    end

    def list
        @client = DropboxClient.new(session[:dropbox_session], ACCESS_TYPE)
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, this works. it was just a little bit confusing that the returned dropboxsession object has always a new instance id. but it is working fine